# Fluoroscopy vs. fluorography

Tags: medical-physics

What is the difference between these two techniques? So far I understand that in Fluoroscopy, it uses a continuous stream of x-rays, where as Fluorography it uses a pulse, but what other differences are there, I have read that Fluoroscopy is used more for posting during a procedure, but surely Fluorography, would be better if you just increase the frame rate.

Also I am slightly confused between how these system a presented, with Fluoroscopy you use a fluorescent screen, which is then presented on a monitor, but what is Fluorography presented on, dose each pulse represent a digital signal and then it convert onto a digital monitor?

If some one could maybe explain the differences, or even link me to a web site that maybe gives a diagram on the different procedure, as when I have searched, for Fluorography I just seem to get search results for Fluoroscopy instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different names for the same thing.

You take a beam of x-rays (continuous or pulsed), detect them with something (fluorescent screen, image intensifier, thin film transistor array), display the images on something.

These days, fluoroscopy systems use an image intensifier or transistor array. Images are captured electronically and displayed on a monitor.

Comment: Ah I see. When you say transistor array, are you referring to direct and indirect methods of digital displays, i.e flat panel and ccd ect.

Comment: Yes. Most of the flat panel detectors I see used in fluoroscopy are the amorphous silicon variety.

Answer (score 2):

As a generalisation:

- Fluoroscopy - the image is viewed on a screen in real time
- Fluorography - a higher resolution image is produced but with an
  increased dose and then viewed later

Answer (score 0):

Fluoroscopy is like seeing a realtime video. Fluorography is like taking pictures.